# What does the - (negative) and + (positive) symbol do inside htaccess Options

Tags: apache

This is the code:

```
<Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

I think I have a pretty good idea of what it does, as the documentation is quite clear:

> The server will follow symbolic links in this directory.

The problem is that all the examples that I see are either

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

or

```
Options -FollowSymLinks
```

But in this case I have code that has neither `+` nor `-`, so what does that mean?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please refer to [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options):

> Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options currently in force.

Hence

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Is equivalent to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI -Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Comment: I don't see that "hence" clear at all. To my it would have been impossible to draw that conclusion... But thanks for the answer :)